# Confidentiality as a Sub-Sub-Sub-Contractor

Tags: software-industry, work-experience, confidentiality

I'm a programmer.  I work for a small contracting company that indirectly does contract work for a very large company.

I was recently contacted by a recruitment company about a position at the very large company.  My company is encouraging me to apply for this direct-hire position.  However, I need to show experience in this industry on my resume.

My challenge is that my secrecy agreements prevent me from disclosing the fact that I have indirect experience with the very large company or the contracting company that works directly with them.  My work has also been very narrowly focused on building specific pages within large applications.  While I'm very good at working with little context, I'm worried that I will not be able to intelligently explain the type of work I've done in the industry without having to disclose details about that work that I'm not allowed to disclose.

How can I best present my experience in an industry to a company I'd like to work for when all the experience I have in the industry is indirectly working for them and I'm not allowed to disclose that I have that experience?

Comment: I can't make sense of the alphabet soup and complex relationships.

Comment: Yeah, me neither.  That's why I'm looking for a direct-hire job.  This chain also messes up everyone's work flow.  In addition, I can't state any names in this question because if someone in the chain sees this and connects it to this chain, they'll see the big picture and know exactly who `BigCompany`, Contract Company `C`, and Contract Company `A` are.  And that would be a problem.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question specifically without knowing specifics. Generally, you can/should list as much as you can without giving things away - for instance, for your position with company X, list "consultant" or whatever your role was, and name the industry. Discuss duties and skills, but not content of work.

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance the use of code blocks is [not encouraged on this site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3941/73791), would you mind changing them to other thing?

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance I have significantly edited your question to try to focus on the specific problem you are trying to get assistance with.  Please review.

Comment: @Eric that edit you made may be the Edit of the Year if you ask me. Excellent edit :)

Comment: Seconded for Edit of the Year.  Thank you for taking my word soup and making it sound perfectly eloquent.  In fact, I may use some of those phrases when speaking with recruiters and HR.  "I'm very good at working with little to no context" and "It's difficult to explain the work I've done without revealing details I'm not allowed to reveal" is by far the best-sounding way to phrase some things I've been trying to say to headhunters for more than 3 years.

Comment: It seems like the company that wants you to take this direct hire position would give you a very good recommendation and solve all this.

Comment: Well... No.  That's the problem.  I'm not actually supposed to be working on any live data or anything for them.  My bosses signed confidentiality agreements.  I did not.  My name is not allowed to appear on anything we do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, what you put in writing and what you say verbally to people in confidence are different things.

In your resume, you should just mention that you have significant experience building a variety of application pages in the industry for a very large company.  You do not not need to name the company, but you can say things like "large, multinational" company.  You can also mention the subject area that your applications relate to.  For example, you might say you built pages in support of "Aerial Reconnaissance Applications".  The point being that you can still disclose the subject area you worked in without disclosing specific project names, company names or any proprietary information.

In terms of an interview, it should be OK to verbally disclose to employees of the very large company that you have indirectly worked with their company and you might mention the internal (i.e. internal to very large company) names of some of the projects you worked on.  If you are very concerned about sensitivity, then only disclose this verbally and only to actual employees of the company.  That is, do not disclose it to your recruiter and do not disclose it to contractors of the very large company.

Comment: I will only mention the world is small, really small, depending on the industry.  If you have secrecy agreements, you really should respect them, don’t put yourself in legal problems due to trying to get “bonus points” for working for a certain employer via sub-contracts

Comment: And if you disclose things about your current employer that you shouldn't, a new employer would fear that you are going to disclose things about them that you shouldn't.

Comment: But the secrecy agreements is to prevent information being leakee to someone else. I don't think they want you to keep it a secret you actually worked for them.

Comment: @Nelson To find out what they want, you would examine whatever was signed.